# Using a pointer to access typedef struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, eeprom

**Objective: Writing to an internal buffer from the values of members of a structure.**

I have a structure that contains members of type Uint16 (unsigned int); here is a small portion of it:

```
typedef unsigned int    Uint16;
typedef struct 
{
    Uint16 ee_Speed_Control_Mode;
    Uint16 ee_Motor_Type;
    Uint16 ee_Max_Electrical_Speed;
    Uint16 ee_Carrier_Frequency;
    Uint16 ee_Rated_Motor_Frequency;
    Uint16 ee_Rated_Motor_Current;
    Uint16 ee_Rs; // extern
    Uint16 ee_Rr; // extern
    Uint16 ee_L_lkg; // extern
    Uint16 ee_Lm;    // extern
    Uint16 ee_No_Load_Current;
    Uint16 ee_Phase_Reversal;
    .....
    .....
} EEPROM_PARAMETERS;

EEPROM_PARAMETERS eepromParameters;
```

**My attempt:**

Here is a function that is intended to write to eeprom: (Most of it is not shown for simplicity; the focus is occurring in the 'for' loop

```
void eeprom_write(Uint16 address, Uint32 *data, Int16 len)
{
    Uint16 i;

    // Multiple bytes will be written
    // Page Write operation will be used
    // Page Write bits to be sent:

    // bit 0: Start condition, a high-to-low transition of SDA with SCL high
    startCondition();

    // bits 1-8: Device address
    I2caRegs.I2CDXR = DEVICE_ADDRESS_WRITE;

    // bit 9: EEPROM outputs 0 as ACK bit
    // Check for ACK bit
    while (I2caRegs.I2CDRR != 0)
    {
        wait();
    }

    // bits 10-17, bit 18 (ACK) and bits 19-26: two 8-bit word addresses
    I2caRegs.I2CDXR = address;

    // After setting the address, page write is capable of writing 64 bytes without stopping
    // The EEPROM will respond with a zero after each data word has been received
    // The data word address lower 6 bits are internally incremented following the receipt of each data word
    // If more than 64 data words are written, data word addresses will "roll over" and previous data will be overwritten

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // How to increment address in data structure?
        I2caRegs.I2CDXR = *data++; 
    }

    // After page write operation is complete, execute stop condition
    stopCondition();
}
```

**When I try to call this function with my parameters..**

```
eeprom_write(0, &eepromParameters, sizeof(eepromParameters) );
```

**I get a incompatible type error:**

```
error #169: argument of type "EEPROM_PARAMETERS *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Uint16 *"
```

My next thought would be that I need a middle man to bring them together and make it a compatible match. Any tips please on what I can try? Thanks

Comment: How is `I2caRegs` defined?

Comment: why not declare as `void eeprom_write(Uint16 address, eepromParameters* data, Int16 len)` ?

Comment: `Uint32 *data` to `eepromParameters* data` . Type you passed is incompatible.

Comment: Uint32 should be Uint16 and the address passed in should be &eepromParameters.ee_Speed_Control_Mode

Comment: @dbush I2caRegs comes from a TI header file. It represents the I2C module control registers

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I meant to have Uint16 in the function definition

Comment: @cup Your suggestion worked, thanks! Post that as an answer if you would like.

Comment: @KS7X You really shouldn't do that, since that code is still broken. Take a look at John Coleman's suggestion.

Comment: @this what do you mean the code is still broken? I did not post the whole function. I tried John Coleman's suggestion: it still gives me an incompatibility error

Comment: @KS7X You have undefined behavior in your code. The suggestion from cup is deceptive, since it removes the compiler warning but doesn't fix the code.

Comment: @this are you referring to the structure? I am aware of this, just needed to call the write function correctly.

Comment: @KS7X As I said, that particular suggestion you used is not correct. Note that a lack of compiler warnings does not imply correct code.

Comment: @this you are being quite vague, I am looking to initially point to the address of the first member of the structure and store that value into the buffer and increment the pointers address each time. Can you please tell me what part of the code you are referring to that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @KS7X The exact part you just described is causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @this yes, thats correct, as far as what is shown above. Assume each member will be defined before the pointer gets a value. Calculations will be done beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the declaration and usage of data.  If you declare it as

```
void eeprom_write(Uint16 address, EEPROM_PARAMETERS* data, Int16 len);
```

and call it as

```
eeprom_write(0, &eepromParameters, sizeof(eepromParameters));
```

It will fall over in

```
*data++
```

since it will increment by the size of EEPROM_PARAMTERS.  If the prototype is declared as

```
void eeprom_write(Uint16 address, UInt16* data, Int16 len);
```

It needs to be called as

```
eeprom_write(0, &eepromParameters.ee_Speed_Control_Mode, sizeof(eepromParameters) / sizeof(Uint16));
```

This assumes that everything in EEPROM_PARAMETERS is Uint16.  Another way of doing this is to use enums.

```
enum EEOffsets
{
    ee_Speed_Control_Mode,
    ee_Motor_Type,
    ee_Max_Electrical_Speed,
    ee_Carrier_Frequency,
    ...
    ee_Max
};

// Initialize the parameters
Uint16 eepromParameters[ee_Max] = { ... };

// If you need to assign
eepromParameters[ee_Carrier_Frequency] = 85;
...
eeprom_write(0, eepromParameters, ee_Max);
```

Comment: You second suggestion( even with your assumption ) is causing undefined behavior via multiple violations. The last example is  however a correct solution.